# Static (PASS_OBJECT<int>) templated array loses data when an object of said type gets created?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, object, static

The problem is self explanatory when running the code where I have two templated classes and one of them is passed into the other. The problem occurs before I pass the templated type `PASS_OBJECT<int>` into the class of type `OBJECT< PASS_OBJECT <int> >` when `OBJECT<PASS_OBJECT <int> > object;` gets created. If you comment out lines 89, 92 and 93 then line 90 shows *In main 2: 99* but otherwise the static templated array gets overwritten (somehow, please explain the theory of static objects if you can). The reason I created a static array in `PASS_OBJECT<int>` was because I wanted to create a larger array (where `const int size = 1000`) and only static allows that otherwise there is a runtime error. This is the execution without commenting out the lines 89, 92 and 93,

```
0
99
99
In main: 99
0
In main: 0
0
0
0
0
```

and this is the execution commenting out lines 89,92 and 93,

```
0
99
99
In main 1: 99
99
In main 2: 99
```

Here's the code,

```
#include <iostream>

const int size = 1;

template <class T>
class PASS_OBJECT;
template <class S>
class OBJECT
{
    private:

        S pass_object;

    public:

    OBJECT();
    ~OBJECT();
    void PASS_OBJECT_TYPE_value(S pass_object, int x, int y);
    void PASS_OBJECT_TYPE_reference(S &pass_object, int x, int y);
};
template <class S>
OBJECT<S>::OBJECT(){}

template <class S>
OBJECT<S>::~OBJECT(){}

template <class S>
void OBJECT<S>::PASS_OBJECT_TYPE_value(S pass_object, int x, int y)
{
    std::cout<<pass_object.return_data( x, y)<<std::endl;
}

template <class S>
void OBJECT<S>::PASS_OBJECT_TYPE_reference(S &pass_object, int x, int y)
{
    std::cout<<pass_object.return_data( x, y)<<std::endl;
}


template <class T>
class PASS_OBJECT
{
    private:

        static T data_array[size][size];

    public:

    PASS_OBJECT();
    ~PASS_OBJECT();
    void insert_data( int data, int x, int y);
    int return_data( int x, int y);
};
template <class T>
T PASS_OBJECT<T>::data_array[size][size];

template <class T>
PASS_OBJECT<T>::PASS_OBJECT()//constructor
{
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                this->data_array[i][j] = 0;
}

template <class T>
PASS_OBJECT<T>::~PASS_OBJECT(){}

template <class T>
void PASS_OBJECT<T>::insert_data( int data, int x, int y)
{
    std::cout<<this->data_array[x][y]<<std::endl;
    this->data_array[x][y] = data;
    std::cout<<this->data_array[x][y]<<std::endl;
}

template <class T>
int PASS_OBJECT<T>::return_data( int x, int y)
{
    std::cout<<this->data_array[x][y]<<std::endl;
    return this->data_array[x][y];
}

int main()
{
    PASS_OBJECT<int> pass_object;
    pass_object.insert_data( 99, 0, 0);
    std::cout<<"In main 1: "<<pass_object.return_data( 0, 0)<<std::endl;

    OBJECT<PASS_OBJECT <int> > object;
    std::cout<<"In main 2: "<<pass_object.return_data( 0, 0)<<std::endl;

    object.PASS_OBJECT_TYPE_value( pass_object, 0, 0);
    object.PASS_OBJECT_TYPE_reference( pass_object, 0, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Objects don't have static classes, but classes have static members. Maybe if you se the right terminology your confusion will abate.

Comment: Right, I know that, but does that mean that every instance of `PASS_OBJECT` now gets created in the same memory space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static member in a class means that there is only one shared instance of this member for all instances of this class. That means that `pass_object` and `object` have the same instance of `data_array` and modifying it in `object` will modify it in `pass_object`. 
To solve your problem about creating large arrays you should use `std::vector` and specify its size in a constructor.

Comment: But what does `std::vector` use to remedy the problem. I'll take your answer if no one else gets it but I really want to know more than just using vectors.

Comment: You get runtime error if you use `data_array[size][size]` with  large sizes because in this case this array is allocated on the stack - very limited chuck of preallocated memory (but very fast). `std::vector` uses dynamic memory allocation - it allocates new memory chunk on the heap in its constructor using `operator new`. You can achieve similar results by writing `T* data_array;` inside the class and writing `data_array = new T[size*size];` in `PASS_OBJECT`s constructor.

Comment: By the way how big of memory is that chunk capable of creating?

Comment: You mean stack? By default about 1MB on windows and 8 MB on linux as I recall, but it varies.